# Passing a single variable to an href in html

Tags: javascript, html

```html
          <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
                      <div class="container-fluid" style="float: right;">
                        <form class="d-flex">
                          <input type="text" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search" style="width: 400px;" id="searchTerm" name="searchTerm" ></input>
                          <script>
                            var inputVal = document.getElementById("searchTerm").value;
                          </script>
                          <a href="/articles/search" class="btn btn-success" onclick="location.href=this.href+'?term='+inputVal;" style="width: 100px;">Search</a>
                
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
```

I am trying to pass the value from the input to a new page and then retrieve that variable on the next page. I am not sure that I am passing it correctly and am not sure how to retrieve it once it is sent to the next page.

Comment: Since the input in a form, you can POST to server side, then retrieve the value from POST and use when you load / GET the new page.

Comment: It's not clear why you're attempting to use JS for this., since you're going to load a new page.  Please edit your question and add a tag for your server side language.

Comment: Adding to what @devlincarnate said: Just set the `action` property of the form and do `submit()` on it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `"change"` event listener:

```
let inputElement = document.querySelector("#searchTerm");

inputElement.addEventListener("change", ()=>{
    let inputVal = document.getElementById("searchTerm").value;
    let anchorElement = document.querySelector(".d-flex > a");
    anchorElement.href = `/articles/search/${inputVal}`;
});
```

Comment: Thanks! This got the variable to the new page. How would I access that variable and use it in the new page?

Comment: This is a convoluted way to implement functionality that already exists in the `form` element as-is.